# "InvocationTargetException" Error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

so, I'm getting an error after trying to load a tab in a Master/Flow layout. The tab that makes the app crash is a calculator with two images and a background image.

Here's the error:

```
04-23 09:21:40.609    1157-1157/endangeredspecies.androidbootcamp.net.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: endangeredspecies.androidbootcamp.net.finalproject, PID: 1157
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at endangeredspecies.androidbootcamp.net.finalproject.ItemDetailFragment.onCreateView(ItemDetailFragment.java:66)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And this is where it is telling me the error is (ItemDetailFragment.java:66):

it is "rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_calculator, container, false);"

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,     container, false);

    if (mItem !=null) {
        if (mItem.id.equals("1")) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_page, container,  false);
        } else if (mItem.id.equals("2")) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_calculator, container, false);
        } else if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
            ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_Detail)).loadUrl(mItem.item_url);
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/calc_background">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtCalc"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@mipmap/spiderman_1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@mipmap/hulk"
    android:layout_marginTop="279dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtAdults"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtChildern"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtAdults"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:hint="@string/txtHint1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtChildren"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtAdults"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:hint="@string/txtHint2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtDays"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtDays"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtChildren"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:hint="@string/txtHint3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtCalcLbl"
    android:id="@+id/btnTotal"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:hint="@string/txtClickCalc"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtTotal"
    android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnTotal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Layout has been added

Comment: why are using mipmap/ for drawables ?

Comment: does it make a difference?

Comment: it shouldn't. The layout looks good. Are you sure that line 66 is pointing to price_calculator ?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. It's so wierd

Comment: are you also sure that mItem.id is != null ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not null